# WordPress site using the kale theme - site appears off screen and needs scrolling to appear on mobile devices

Tags: wordpress, mobile, scroll, off-screen

I have a problem with formatting.
I have built a *WordPress* site: [cookingacademy.co.il](http://cookingacademy.co.il).
I used the *kale theme* for the site.

When using a mobile device sometimes the site appears off the screen and you need to scroll to make it appear on the screen.

This is a picture of the problem:

[image: This is a picture of the problem:]

How can I fix that?

Comment: FYI: Your site look great. Your recipes look delicious. Is there an english translation of the cooking recipes?

Answer (score 0):

open up your main.css file 
(you can find this in your wordpress dashboard > appearance > editor)

add this at the very end of the file.

```
 *{
     overflow-x: hidden;
 }
```

save it.
refresh.

There's something there that is just very very large and is not being handled by the  theme.